# TFTP Error code 1: File not found

Tags: networking, tftp

When I'm sending a file through TFTP remotely, it shows an error like

```
tftp> put MYMIBTable.txt /home/amsys/Desktop/              
Error code 1: File not found
```

What is the problem? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Add `-c` flag to `server_args` in your `tftp xinet.d` config.

Change

```
server_args = -l -s /tftpboot
```

To

```
server_args = -c -s /tftpboot
```

And make sure that `user = nobody`

Comment: Faced this issue when my tftp file in xinetd.d did not have any flags for server_args, adding these arguments did not solve it either.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the reverse also, using a 'get' from the other machine as the client.

It turned out the filename I was using was too long.

When I shortened it everything was fine.

The filename I was using was 34 characters long and I changed it to 19. I did not test for the maximum length, possibly 32 characters.